# Referencing a Collection defined in Java FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have the following Java code:

```
@DefaultProperty("strings")
public class CustomControl extends HBox {
 ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox();
 public ObservableList<String> getStrings() {
  return choiceBox.getItems();
 }
}
```

And the following FXML code:

```
<CustomControl>
  <String fx:value="value1" />
  <String fx:value="value2" />
</CustomControl>
```

This works fine, but if I replace the FXML code with the following FXML code, it doesn't work:

```
<fx:define>
 <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList" fx:id="collection">
  <String fx:value="value1" />
  <String fx:value="value2" />
 </FXCollections>
</fx:define>
...
<CustomControl>
 <fx:reference source="collection" />
</CustomControl>
```

When I run this, I get the following type of error:

```
Unable to coerce [value1, value2] to class String.
```

I understand the error (It thinks that I want to put the whole list of strings into the first element of the "strings" bean, when really I want each item in the list to be added to the "strings" bean), but I don't know how to do what I want to do.
The idea is, I am trying to define a list of items in the beginning of the fxml file so that I can reference that list multiple times in other parts of the fxml file. I don't know how many items will be in this list, so I don't want to give each item it's own id. How do I reference a sequence of elements without getting the parent element? Or is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version of your code, if you give an `fx:id` to the `CustomControl`:

```
<CustomControl fx:id="customControl">
  <String fx:value="value1" />
  <String fx:value="value2" />
</CustomControl>
```

then you should be able to reference the list elsewhere in the FXML file with

```
${customControl.strings}
```

as an attribute value, or

```
<fx:reference source="customControl.strings"/>
```

as an element.

Alternatively, I think the second approach works if you define a `setStrings(...)` method in the `CustomControl` class, e.g.:

```
@DefaultProperty("strings")
public class CustomControl extends HBox {
 ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox();
 public ObservableList<String> getStrings() {
  return stringsProperty().get();
 }
 public void setStrings(ObservableList<String> strings) {
  stringsProperty().set(strings);
 }
 public ObjectProperty<ObservableList<String>> stringsProperty() {
  return choiceBox.itemsProperty();
 }
}
```

With this version, the `DefaultProperty` doesn't seem to respect the `setStrings(...)` method, but if you explicitly specify the property it works:

```
<fx:define>
 <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList" fx:id="collection">
  <String fx:value="value1" />
  <String fx:value="value2" />
 </FXCollections>
</fx:define>
...
<CustomControl>
 <strings>
  <fx:reference source="collection" />
 </strings>
</CustomControl>
```

Comment: Ok, I got this working now using a variation of your second approach after the modification. That defaultproperty gotcha was annoying. Thank you so much!